# sap.m.List Items removing attribute at runtime

Tags: sapui5

Based on condition, i want to remove one of the element(highlighted in the img)[image] from Custom List. Here is the code i did.Is it the right way of doing?
If i pass null to the formatter, as Avatar icon by default it shows one and the icon should not be displayed for null value.
View::`

```
<VBox>
            <List id="sonarRepId" items="{ path: 'sonarMetrics>/measures' }" updateFinished="onUpdateListFinished">
                <items>
                    <CustomListItem id="idSonarList">
                        <FlexBox id="idFlex" alignItems="Start" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" height="88px">
                            <items>
                                <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                    <Link text="{sonarMetrics>value}" press="handlePress" class="sonarsapMLnk"/>
                                    <HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                                        <core:Icon size="2rem" class="sonarsapMObjLIcon" src="{sonarMetrics>imageL}"/>
                                        <Label text="{sonarMetrics>name}" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
                                    </HBox>
                                    <layoutData>
                                        <FlexItemData growFactor="2"/>
                                    </layoutData>
                                </VBox>
                                <HBox id="idHbox" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                    <items>
                                        <HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                            <Link id="idLinkState" text="{sonarMetrics>state}" press="stateHandlePress" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>
                                            <Avatar id="idAvatar" initials="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatNumeric'}" displaySize="XS"
                                                backgroundColor="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatIconColor'}"/>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </items>
                                </HBox>
                            </items>
                        </FlexBox>
                    </CustomListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
        </VBox>
```

Controller

```
onUpdateListFinished: function (oEvent) {
            // var sonarList = this.getView().byId("sonarRepId");
            // var items = sonarList.getItems();
            // for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            //  var oAvatarIcon = oEvent.getSource().getItems()[i].mAggregations.content[0].mAggregations.items[1].mAggregations.items[0].mAggregations.items[1];
            //  if(oAvatarIcon){
            //  var delItemColor = oAvatarIcon.getProperty("backgroundColor");
            //  if (delItemColor === "Accent10") {
            //      oAvatarIcon.destroy();
            //  }
            // }
            // }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the Avatar control instead of destroying it. You can use [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.9/docs/guide/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af.html) for this.

Expression Binding:

```
visible="{= ${sonarMetrics>state_value} !== null}"
```

The Avatar control:

```
<Avatar id="idAvatar" visible="{= ${sonarMetrics>state_value} !== null}" 
initials="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatNumeric'}" 
displaySize="XS" backgroundColor="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatIconColor'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

alexP mentioned of ExpressionBinding which is accurate.

I would like to suggest that the below way of handling is more effective and handles more test cases.

visible="{= !!${sonarMetrics>state_value}}"